# does anyone know how to stop repeat in lua script when button is pressed?

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

So I'm currently writing a rapid fire script for game. here is what i got

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event, arg)
  if IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then
    if  IsMouseButtonPressed(1)then
      repeat
        Sleep(math.random(30, 60))
        PressMouseButton(1)
        Sleep(math.random(30, 60))
        ReleaseMouseButton(1)

      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end
  end
end
```

So it auto clicks the left mouse button when capslock is on and lmb is hold.
However, sometimes even if I release the left mouse button, the script still kept going, so does anyone know how to solve this?
Or in another way, is there a way to stop the repeat loop when the "R" button or the "shift" button is pressed?
thx

Comment: how long does it continue? why do you press a button that is already pressed? what happens if you ReleaseMouseButton while holding it down? which hof the states has priority?

Answer (score 1):

You can not simulate LMB press and listen for its state simultaneously.
The simplest solution is to assign another key for fire ingame instead of LMB.
I assume you have assigned <kbd>P</kbd> key for shooting.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
      if IsKeyLockOn("capslock") then
         repeat
            PressKey("P")
            Sleep(math.random(30, 60))
            ReleaseKey("P")
            Sleep(math.random(30, 60))
         until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
      end
      PressKey("P")
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 1 then
      ReleaseKey("P")
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using LOVE2D, I recommend you try the love.mouse.isDown feature. You can find out more at this link: https://love2d.org/wiki/love.mouse

Comment: the quesiton is about Logitechs G-Series Lua API.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).